# I need to find the missing Id's from the table after checking the min and max id's from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to find the missing id's from the table `#a` below:

```
id  |SEQ|Text
1   |1  |AA
1   |3  |CC
1   |4  |DD
1   |5  |EE
1   |6  |FF
1   |7  |GG
1   |8  |HH
1   |10 |JJ
2   |1  |KK
2   |2  |LL
2   |3  |MM
2   |4  |NN
2   |6  |PP
2   |7  |QQ
3   |1  |TT
3   |4  |ZZ
3   |5  |XX
```

The max and min SEQ of the table `#a` is stored in another table `#b`:

```
id| mn| mx
1 | 1 | 12
2 | 1 | 9
3 | 1 | 5
```

My query below is giving the correct output but the execution is expensive. Is there another way to solve this?

```
with cte
as
(
    select id, mn, mx
    from #b

    union all

    select id, mn, mx -1
    from cte
    where mx-1 > 0
)
select
    cte.id, cte.mx
from
    cte
    left join #a on cte.id = #a.id and cte.mx = #a.seq
where
    #a.seq is null
order by cte.id, cte.mx
```

There are mainly 2 problems in this query:

1. The query is running very slow. The above records are just example. In real database I have 50,000 rows.
   [image]
2. I tried to understand the execution plan to detect the hiccups. However I could not understand some part of it, which I have highlighted in Red.

It would be great if someone could help me here. I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use recursive CTE to [generate a set of numbers](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1). It is quite inefficient way to do it (see charts for generating 50K numbers [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)). I'd recommend to have a persisted table of numbers in the database. I, personally, have a table `Numbers` with 100K rows with one column `Number`, which is a primary key, which has integer numbers from 1 to 100,000.

Once you have such table, your query is simplified to this:

```
SELECT
    #b.id, #b.mx
FROM
    #b
    INNER JOIN Numbers ON 
        #b.mx >= Numbers.Number AND
        #b.mn <= Numbers.Number -- use this clause if mn can be more than 1
    LEFT JOIN #a ON
        #a.id = #b.id AND
        #a.seq = Numbers.Number
WHERE
    #a.seq IS NULL
ORDER BY #b.id, #b.mx
```

Also, it goes without saying, that you have to make sure that you have index on `#b` on `id`, plus index on `#a` on `(id, seq)`.

Comment: Thanks man. Its a good method to generate number from sys.all_objects. I will test its performance tomorrow when I go to work. But I am sure this method will increase the query performance. Thanks once again for you time

Comment: @sam, if you have a persisted table of numbers, it will have a primary key (unique index). It is important to have an index if you want performance.

Answer (score 1):

Two things that come to my mind are:

- Use a numbers / tally table. Either by creating a normal table or create a virtual using CTE. Use that to find numbers that don't exist.
- If there's not a lot of missing numbers, you can use a trick with row_number() to find the ranges of numbers that don't have any gaps with something like this:

  ```
  select id, min(seq), max(seq) 
  from (
    select
      id,
      seq,
      seq - row_number () over (partition by id order by SEQ asc) GRP
    from
      table1
  ) X group by id, GRP
  order by 1
  ```

This will of course need more handling after you have find the ranges of numbers that exists.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how does row_number helps you find ranges ? I didn't see how it can help http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/345587

Comment: @RoyiNamir You're partitioning with a, so you're row numbers are always 1, remove that.

Comment: Thank you. you're right. PS what if `a` doesn't start with `1` ? how can I _align_ the row_number offset ?

Answer (score 0):

CTE is just syntax and is most likely getting evaluated multiple times
Materialize the CTE output to a #temp and join to the #temp